# Is there any way to delete widget by its position in grid or delete row in this grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to have ability to create endless widgets by .addWidget (in grid, new widget - new row). I already have it. But im also need ability to delete widgets by his position. I tried this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTime, QTimer, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLCDNumber, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QGroupBox
import sys
from somethingtestui import Ui_MainWindow

global selection
selection = 1


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(mywindow, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add)

def add(self):
    global selection
    self.row = QTextEdit('')
    self.text3 = QPushButton('Delete row')
    self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.row, selection, 0, 1, 1)
    self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.text3, selection, 1, 1, 1)
    # global delf
    def delf():
        global selection
        selection = selection-1
        number = self.ui.gridLayout.itemAtPosition(selection,1)
        print(number)
        self.row.deleteLater()
        self.rrow = None
        self.text3.deleteLater()
        self.text3 = None
    self.text3.clicked.connect(delf)
    selection = selection+1
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

With it i can add many widgets. If there are one created widget i am free to delete it and repeat it. But if there are 2 or more created widget i can delete one of them, and after click button "Delete" in the other row it crash:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programs\YandexDisk\Tempfiles\TournamentBot\testi22.py", line 31, in delf
    self.row.deleteLater()
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QTextEdit has been deleted
```

Comment: Trying to keep track of the index of your widgets in the layout using a global variable is almost always a bad idea. Also, when an item is removed from a grid layout, the other items will be renumbered, so if you delete a widget later, it's index in the layout will likely not be the same as at the time it was added to the layout. Instead of deleting the widgets you are probably better of hiding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for myself

```
from somethingtestui import Ui_MainWindow

global rowcnt
rowcnt = 1


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
    super(mywindow, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add)
    self.ui.gridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(50,50)
    self.ui.gridLayout.setColumnMinimumWidth(50,50)

def add(self):
    global rowcnt
    self.row = QTextEdit('')
    self.delbtn = QPushButton('Delete row')
    self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.row, rowcnt, 0, 1, 1)
    self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.delbtn, rowcnt, 1, 1, 1)
    w = self.ui.gridLayout.itemAtPosition(rowcnt,1).widget()
    def delf(currow):
        global rowcnt
        rowcnt = rowcnt-1
        number = self.ui.gridLayout.itemAtPosition(currow,1).widget()
        number2 = self.ui.gridLayout.itemAtPosition(currow,0).widget()
        number.deleteLater()
        number2.deleteLater()
    w.clicked.connect(lambda: delf(mrowcnt))
    rowcnt = rowcnt+1
    mrowcnt = rowcnt-1
```